# Как перейти с разработки сайтов на PHP на NodeJS?

Tags: node.js

Пока учился в университете самостоятельно освоил разработку сайтов с нуля и сейчас работаю Full Stack - JavaScript + PHP + Postgresql. Хочу пересесть с PHP на NodeJS в связи с чем есть вопрос:

Сейчас у меня проекты устроены так: есть движок, к которому ходят AJAX-запросы и из которого импортируются классы, содержащие методы в файлы-генераторы страниц. И есть index.php файлы, на которые nginx перенаправляет запросы. Когда открывается страница - исполняется PHP-код, который вызывает функцию, возвращающую данные. Затем идёт html-код в котором используются отрывки php-кода. Как это организовать на NodeJS? Какой стэк технологий нужен? Хватит ли мне nginx + express + nodejs + moustache? Правильно ли я понимаю, что мне нужно использовать nginx в качестве прокси-сервера к express, на уровне express реализовывать маршрутизацию запросов, а затем на уровне NodeJS брать данные из базы и возвращать клиенту html-код, сгенерированный при помощи шаблонов Moustache? И можно ли использовать TypeScript на стороне сервера NodeJS, считается ли это нормальной практикой?

Извините за возможно очень глупые вопросы, но уж больно мне надоел PHP. Хочу попробовать что-то новое и современное.

Answer (score 1):

> уж больно мне надоел PHP. Хочу попробовать что-то новое и современное.

А, чем Вас PHP обидел? Вы уже освоили и применяете каждый день в работе все новшества PHP 7.X?

> Хватит ли мне nginx + express + nodejs + moustache?

Возможно.

А, вообще просто поймите, что любой язык, любая библиотека и т.д., это всего лишь инструмент в руках программиста. Не более.

Конечно везде есть свои плюсы и минусы, но в конечном итоге именно программист определяет насколько эффективно будет работать его детище. Не хочу никого обидеть, но пословицу о плохом танцоре знают почти все
.
Правильно ли я понимаю, что мне нужно использовать nginx в качестве прокси-сервера к express, на уровне express реализовывать маршрутизацию запросов, а затем на уровне NodeJS брать данные из базы и возвращать клиенту html-код, сгенерированный при помощи шаблонов Moustache?

Обычно примерно так всё и работает, если пишете "монолит".

> И можно ли использовать TypeScript на стороне сервера NodeJS,
>   считается ли это нормальной практикой?

Да. Многие так делают.

Comment: Спасибо за развёрнутый ответ. Касаемо PHP и чем он меня обидел. Во-первых, мне кажется, что с PHP я трачу больше времени на написание кода чем на Javascript. Во-вторых, мне гораздо больше нравится npm чем composer. В-третьих, субъективно мне больше нравится стиль кода JS чем PHP. В-четвёртых, мне нравится идея использовать один язык для разработки на сервере и на клиенте одновременно. Очень часто замечаю, что совершаю ошибки при частом переключении между PHP и JS.

Comment: Ну, здесь уже хозяин-барин...